# Small byte[] chunks cause Image corruption

Tags: c#, asp.net, stream, .net

I'm trying to copy a file to a web handler in small block sizes. It works fine when the buffer is relatively large and always when it is the size of the image. But I get image distortion of the block sizes are too small.

Why would it change when I"m putting the same bytes back together again?

```
OpenFileDialog o = new OpenFileDialog();
o.ShowDialog();

using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
{
    int index = 0;
    var tmpName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    const int chunkSize = 10*1024;

    webClient.Headers.Add("Filename", "");

    using (var file = o.OpenFile())
    {

        int bytesRead;
        //Using ChunkSize will give image distortion. But file.length works. So does dividing by 10 to result in 10 chunks. Why?
        byte[] buffer = new byte[file.Length/10];

        int position = 0;
        while (position < file.Length)
        {
            if (position + buffer.Length > file.Length)
            {
                buffer = new byte[file.Length - position];
            }
            bytesRead = file.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            position += bytesRead;

            var fileName = string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}", tmpName, index, o.SafeFileName);
            webClient.Headers["Filename"] = fileName;
            //webClient.Headers["blockSize"] = buffer.Length.ToString();
            webClient.UploadData("http://localhost:49815/FileUpload.ashx", buffer);
            index++;

        }

    }
    var values = new NameValueCollection();
    values.Add("Filename", string.Format("{0}.{1}", tmpName, o.SafeFileName));
    values.Add("Complete", "true");
    webClient.Headers.Clear();
    webClient.UploadValues("http://localhost:49815/FileUpload.ashx", values);



}
```

**What I've tested**

- If I don't pass to the chunks to the fileupload.ashx and just put the chunks back together on the client app it works fine.
- The file size matches exactly on the server side.
- Same problem happens saving broken up file to the same location. So HTTP has nothing to do with it.

  ```
  private void CombineFiles(string filename)
  {
      var fileguid = filename.Substring(0, filename.IndexOf(".") + 1);
      var shortFileName = filename.Replace(fileguid, "");

      var files = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "images", fileguid + "*");
      using (var filestream = File.Create(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "images/" + shortFileName))
      {
          foreach (string file in files)
          {
              var fileBuffer = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
              filestream.Write(fileBuffer, 0, fileBuffer.Length);
              File.Delete(file);

          }
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

ugh. Dumb problem. The files were getting out of order because my naming scheme was 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10. So when it got to ten the values were 1,10,2,3,4...

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "images");
var files = directory.GetFiles(fileguid + "*").OrderBy(x => x.CreationTime).ToArray();
```

Silly mistake.